# Display and edit user profie in a custom componet

Tags: joomla-3.x, component, plugin, custom-module

i am creating a customer dashboard component in joomla 3.2, so i want to display user profile fields to my view and able to edit fields as well, i am displaying them manually using
`$this->user = JFactory::getUser();` and `<?php echo $this->user->name; ?>`
now i have to add the functionality to edit as well, like password, profile image etc.
how could i implement this functionality to my custom component.

Comment: I would suggest you look at how `com_users` does it ;)

Comment: yes i had gone through com_users, but i think it is complicated, or in may be i am getting the flow correctly, is their any simple way of doing thing manually. like creating the form and posting it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just an idea for a quick implementation: You could add a modal link to the com_users edit profile view in your component's view.

At the top of your view add:

```
JHTML::_('behavior.modal');
```

Then link like below:

```
<a class="modal" href="index.php?option=com_users&view=profile&layout=edit&tmpl=component?" rel="{handler: 'iframe', size: {x: 640, y: 540}}"> Edit Login Details</a>
```

This will open the edit profile layout in a modal window, without leaving your current page and have the com_users do the job, instead of re-creating the same functionality.

Comment: Thanks! @FFrewin, for now being im doing like this way only, displaying in popup modal. Additional, i have to  remove basic settings fields from the com_user -> user profile as well.

Comment: though i am just calling that functionality here in my component, but for later use what method would be better so that i will be completely free to edit as i want in user profile section.

Comment: Note: To only retreive the profile values you can use:  $profile = JUserHelper::getProfile($userid);